# Unable to configure Web Application Proxy in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, adfs, web-application-proxy

While configuring WAP in the server I am getting the below error. Both WAP server and ADFS server are in the same Azure region and network.

**Powershell error**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you lack this parameter `-FederationServiceTrustCredential` when you run `Install-WebApplicationProxy` cmdlet. You can add it like the following example:

```
$FScredential = Get-Credential
Install-WebApplicationProxy -FederationServiceName "FS01.Contoso.com" -FederationServiceTrustCredential $FScredential -CertificateThumbprint "0a1b2c3d0a1b2c3d0a1b2c3d0a1b2c3d0a1b2c3d"
```

References: [Install-WebApplicationProxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webapplicationproxy/install-webapplicationproxy?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Same error. Even if we are not passing -FederationServiceTrustCredential, PS will ask for the credentials during execution. The error is related to something else. I have tried all the ways including reinstalling adfs and wap in a new instance as well. But I am able to configure if I do from a 2016 server.

Comment: What is that test environment when this error happen?